# How web server know when is postback or when is initial request?

Tags: asp.net, web, client-server

Very simple. After web client (web browser) sends request to web server, web client expecting and recieving response from web server. After that (on from submit) web client sends some data to web server(postback). But, internally how web server knows what is postback or what is first request for the web page (maybe some flag in HTTP request?)?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP has many verbs, such as `POST` and `GET`. `GET` is like typing in the URL. `POST` is usually used for forms.

If the page method is `POST`, this should get set (in ASP.NET).

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{

}
```

Comment: Ok, but what happens internally in HTTP request parameters?

Comment: +1 beat me by 0.5s just because I was re-reading and making sure that was actually asked :)

Comment: Doesn't matter if web server is IIS or Apache. Web client sends HTTP request with some fields/parameter. How web server investigate what parameter tells him if request is postback or only requst for the web page?

Comment: @SilverDeveloper its by the HTTP verb.

Comment: I think that difference between GET and POST is only in a way how data are encoded (http://stevenclark.com.au/2008/01/12/get-vs-post-for-the-beginner/ http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html). I try to make request via HTTP poster in Firefox and choose POST method. Web app (ASP .NET) doesn't recognized that request as postback.

Comment: @SilverDeveloper is correct, and this answer is incorrect. The first request to a page will not be considered a postback regardless of the method used.

Answer (score 0):

While only being a part of the whole story, this probably is the most relevant excerpt of the `System.Web.UI.Page` class:

In Method `ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)`:

```
if (this._requestValueCollection != null) {
    [..]
    text2 = this._requestValueCollection["__CALLBACKID"];
    if (text2 != null && this._request.HttpVerb == HttpVerb.POST)
    {
        this._isCallback = true;
    }
[..]
}
```

Obviously ASP.NET is transmitting an encrypted `__CALLBACKID` in the post parameters and also checks if the POST verb is set in the HTTP request message.

Answer (score 0):

If we're just talking about IIS/server - then it *can't (on it's own)*. The *first request* can be any verb (`GET`, `POST`, or any other you allow).

If we're talking about ASP.NET Web forms pages, you *can assume* (but not 100%) that the "first" request is a `GET` and a "postback", by nature of the term itself is a `POST`. But just like above, you can create an ASP.Net page that takes a `POST` as **it's** first request.

As a developer you can create ways to identify the "first request", however you define it. It's your way of perhaps enforcing a flow. The verb really doesn't have anything to do with identifying the "first (http) request"....

Comment: From what I could find when checking the source, the verb actually matters. (see my answer) Also it's probably not that easy to fake a postback to ASP.NET, because the relevant data is sent encrypted.

Comment: @atticae Sure in the **context _(only)_ of ASP.Net Web Forms** - and even then it's not as if that's some sort of rule. If you were to pass data from page1.aspx to page2.aspx, via `POST`, then the "first request" that page2.aspx gets is a `POST`....

Comment: Yes, that's a cross page postback then. And as you see in my answer above, the verb is not everything that is checked.